# Show statistics of my community ads, on all sites

Tags: support, script-request

In January I posted community ads to various sites I belong to.
From time to time I want to see how they perform, so for each site I craft the `display` URL manually and launch it in a browser:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/281524
```

[image: Ads]

It is quite a pain to remember what sites I posted ads to, and craft these URLs.
It would be great if there was a script or something that showed me all of my ads across all networks, each with:

- Score
- Created date
- Clicks per day
- Total clicks

Restricting to only ads that have at least 6 upvotes is OK, but it would be even better to show all.

Comment: Hmmm I don't know how this would be made - there's no API to see Community Ads so the only way to see the ads would to GET the page, but then CORS would probably come into play and block any access from another site... but +1 and I'm favouriting this question - I'd like to see how this can be done if someone does it! :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, It's not hard but involves a few steps.  I'd do it if any of: [1] It took 15 minutes or less (estimate is 2-3 hours); [2] I would use it (not likely); [3] There was a big enough interest (doubtful), [4] I already had a *very* similar project that could easily be tweaked (not yet), or [5] Someone somehow made it worth my while (doubtful).

Comment: @BrockAdams lol fair enough - seems like it would be a tedious process! But how? You can't GET the page, and can't use the API, so what other way is there to access the information!?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, You determined to make me spend time on this? ;)  Anywho: (1) get user's associated meta accounts. (2) for each account, pull Q's that have the reserved tag (Much less involved than pulling all of user's A's). Use filter that also gives answer info. (3) extract A's that belong to user, (4) correlate with the `/ads/display/` page for that Q (may also be hidden API can use), (5) Display results -- a web page app seems best.

Comment: @BrockAdams lol...nothing like that ;) What's puzzling me is step 4 - how would you access the info on `/ads/display` from *a different domain*? CORS will hinder you won't it??

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ: May be API.  Also SE is usually good about that, probably has CORS set okay.  Worst case, have to write extension or userscript (doubt is needed).